# MySQL not using Index (despite FORCE INDEX)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

I need to do a live search using PHP and jQuery to select cities and countries from the two tables `cities` (almost 3M rows) and `countries` (few hundred rows).

For a short moment I was thinking of using a `MyISAM` table for `cities` as `InnoDB` does not support `FULLTEXT` search, however decided it is not a way to go (frequent table crashes, all other tables are `InnoDB` etc and with MySQL 5.6+ `InnoDB` also starts to support `FULLTEXT` index).

So, right now I still use MySQL 5.1, and as most cities consist of one-word only or max 2-3 Words, but e.g. "New York" - most people will not search for "York" if they mean "New York". So, I just put an index on the `city_real` column (which is a varchar).

The following query (I tried it in different versions, without any `JOIN` and without `ORDER BY`, with `USE INDEX` and even with `FORCE INDEX`, I have tried LIKE instead equal (=) but another post said = was faster and if the wildcard is only at the end, it is OK to use it), in `EXPLAIN` it always says "using where, using filesort". The average time for the query is about 4sec, which you have to admit is a little bit to slow for a live search (user typing in text-box and seeing suggestions of cities and countries)...

Live search (jQuery ajax) searches if the user typed at least 3 characters...

```
SELECT ci.id, ci.city_real, co.country_name FROM cities ci LEFT JOIN countries co ON(ci.country_id=co.country_id) WHERE city_real='cit%' ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5
```

There is a `PRIMARY` on `ci.id` and an `INDEX` on `ci.city_real`. Any ideas why MySQL does not use the index? Or how I could speed up the query? Or where else I should/should not set an `INDEX`?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

---

Here's the explain output

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  ci  range   city_real   city_real   768 NULL    1250    Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  co  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 6   fibsi_1.ci.country_id   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `WHERE city_real LIKE 'cit%'`, not `WHERE city_real='cit%'`.

> I have tried LIKE instead equal (=) but another post said = was faster and if the wildcard is only at the end, it is OK to use it

This is wrong. `=` doesn't support wildcards so it will give you the wrong results.

> Or how I could speed up the query?

Make sure you have an index on `country_id` in both tables. Post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

The query do use index as seen in the `key` field of explain output. The reason it uses filesort is the order by, and the reason it uses where is probably one of the fields (city_real, population) allows null values.